# Default value of margin in css

Tags: css, margin

I have doubt regarding margins in css's box model . I know what is it , how to set and what is margin collapsing but what confusing me is what happens when we do not provide any value to element's margin property . It doesn't stick to it's neighboring element . But the default value is of margin 0. So does it work? When I tried the two elements do not touch each other. Am i Missing something to understand? Kindly explain

Comment: Can you show some code with a real example? The default margin (if there is one) is likely to be dictated by the browser, possibly differently for every element.

Answer (score 4):

The initial value is `0` here: https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/margin-left

But your browser may set default value for some elements: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

If you want to remove the margin, you can write `margin: 0;`.